# When I install Elementary OS it boots to UBUNTU!

Tags: boot, desktop

I have tried multiple times to install Elementary os 5.1 on a win 10 machine either in "try" or "install" mode. However it boots into UBUNTU!! Do not know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you have downloaded the ISO from the official site** and that you have created a Bootable usb key from this ISO image and not another. There should be no problem testing or installing Elementary OS.

[HERE](https://www.elementaryos-fr.org/telecharger-elementary-os/) the official place for download the ISO